# How can I remove wishlist and compare block pieces form the 404 not found page?

Tags: magento2, layout, wishlist, cms-pages, compare

I need to remove wishlist and compare from the not found page. I use CMS to make the not found page. This is what I tried as a Design XML Update, and it didn't work:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />
 </referenceContainer>
```

and:

```
<referenceContainer name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true" />
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just switched to 1-column template and all is correct. I just didn't clear the cache well the first time. Well, I did, but it was still something left and displaying the page wrongly.